# JS maximum call stack exceeded P5

Tags: javascript, class, object, recursion, p5.js

I am trying to make program to count the biggest color connected blocks in p5.js. The problem is that when I call recursively the box neighbours it gives - "The maximum call stack exceed" and I know what means the error, but I don't know why it happens. Here is my code:

```html
class Box {
  constructor(id, x, y, w, h, col, colId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.col = col;
    this.colId = colId;
  }

  render() {
    fill(this.col);
    stroke(1);
    rect(this.x * this.w, this.y * this.w, this.w, this.h);
  }

  getNeighbour(visited, x, y) {
    if(x - 1 < 0 || x + 1 >= rows || y - 1 < 0 || y + 1 >= cols) {
      return -1; 
    }
    else {
      this.col = color(10,10,10);
      arr[x-1][y].getNeighbour(visited,x-1,y);
      arr[x+1][y].getNeighbour(visited,x+1,y);
      arr[x][y-1].getNeighbour(visited,x,y-1);
      arr[x][y+1].getNeighbour(visited,x,y+1);
    }
    if(!this.contains(this.id)) {
      visited.push(this.id); 
    }
    
    
    
  }
  
  contains() {
    for(let i = 0; i < visited.length; i++) {
      if(this.id == visited[i]) return true; 
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Please tell me where the problem is. I also tried doing the check one at the time. First for the left neighbour and that works like charm. But when i add the right one too this error shows up. I think i have proper default cases that are met, but the reality may be different.

Comment: beside the stack, why do you check all indixes (`x` or `y`) in advance if you do not need to check a value, because the direction is possible. i think you should check in front of the call of `getNeighbour`.

Comment: I will check for value later, but i removed it to be easier for now.

Comment: where is the check if a box was `visited`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
else {
  this.col = color(10,10,10);
  arr[x-1][y].getNeighbour(visited,x-1,y);
  arr[x+1][y].getNeighbour(visited,x+1,y);
  arr[x][y-1].getNeighbour(visited,x,y-1);
  arr[x][y+1].getNeighbour(visited,x,y+1);
}
if(!this.contains(this.id)) {
  visited.push(this.id); 
}
```

try:

```
else if(!this.contains(this.id)) {
  visited.push(this.id);
  this.col = color(10,10,10);
  arr[x-1][y].getNeighbour(visited,x-1,y);
  arr[x+1][y].getNeighbour(visited,x+1,y);
  arr[x][y-1].getNeighbour(visited,x,y-1);
  arr[x][y+1].getNeighbour(visited,x,y+1);
}
```

Further: I'm not sure that `this.contains` is the right thing to do, maybe try: `visited.contains...` ?

Answer (score 2):

When you start with a box, it recurses to the box left, right, above and below it.
Same happens for those four boxes.
But if you are on the box above and it calls the box below, you are back where you started. This goes back and forth, until your stack runs out.

Depending on what you are trying to do, a simple solution would be to pull the "contains" check up, and abort if the box was visited before:

```js
getNeighbour(visited, x, y) {
    if( isOutsideBounds(x,y) || visited.indexOf(this.id) > -1) {
      return -1; 
    }
    this.col = color(10,10,10);
    visited.push(this.id)
    arr[x-1][y].getNeighbour(visited,x-1,y);
    arr[x+1][y].getNeighbour(visited,x+1,y);
    arr[x][y-1].getNeighbour(visited,x,y-1);
    arr[x][y+1].getNeighbour(visited,x,y+1); 
}
```

Also, it seems like your `contains()` function accesses the `visited` array, which is not in the function's scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is an abstract approach. You could take an island counter and count the items of each island.

```js
function check(array) {

    function test(array, i, j, value) {
        if (array[i] && array[i][j] === -1) {
            count[value] = (count[value] || 0) + 1;
            array[i][j] = value;
            test(array, i - 1, j, value);
            test(array, i + 1, j, value);
            test(array, i, j - 1, value);
            test(array, i, j + 1, value);
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    var value = 1,
        count = {};

    array.forEach(a=> a.forEach((b, i, bb) => bb[i] = -b));
    array.forEach((a, i, aa) => a.forEach((b, j) => test(aa, i, j, value) && value++));
    array.map(a => console.log(...a));
    return count;
}

console.log(check([[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]));
console.log(check([[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]));
console.log(check([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```